# jQuery slideDown callback if complete or fail.. 'always' option

Tags: jquery

Silly question but i can't seem to figure it out.

In the jquery documents it shows an option in the slideUp() function which is "always". which will call a function once the animation completes or fails
How do i implement this?

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

```
$(".toHide").slideUp(function(){
   alert();
})
```

basically want that alert to be called no matter what after the animation.. currently only calls if it completes not fail.

**animation fails if the class doesnt yet exist**

Comment: Please post a complete code example. A jsFiddle.net example would be helpful too.

Comment: An animation can fail?

Comment: How would a `slideUp` fail

Comment: @ChenAsraf +1 for making me chuckle

Comment: @ChenAsraf +1 from me too.

Comment: Thanks fort the love guys, but turns out I was wrong... An animation can "fail" if it is stopped mid-way by design

Comment: yes, I also saw that "fail
Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd )
A function to be called when the animation fails to complete (its Promise object is rejected). (version added: 1.8)"

Comment: @ChenAsraf: *"How would a slideUp fail?"* If you cancel it with `stop`: http://jsbin.com/ifoqov/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ifoqov/1/edit)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I figured that out, look at my comment aboce ^ :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All animations can generate promise objects which have an `always` method.

```
$(".toHide").slideUp().promise().always(function(){
    alert("foobar");
});
```

<strike>however, animations can't *"fail"*, so it's irrelevant anyway.</strike>

Comment: Are you using a recent version of jQuery? If you're using something older than 1.8, there is no fail callback, which also means there's no always callback.

Comment: OMG.. flip.. how did i not see that.. miss typed the version haha. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Options are typically in the format of `{option: optionVal, option2: option2Val}`

```
$('.toHide').slideUp({ 
  always: function(Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd){}
});
```

Comment: @DustinSilk: The `Promise` and `Boolean` above aren't real code, the above is pseudocode.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My mistake. Better?

Answer (score 1):

you can also do

```
$.when(
    $('.toHide').slideUp()
).always(
    function() {
        alert('');
    }
);
```

Comment: could only be if jQuery is < 1.5